# Node.js callback from one controller method to other

Tags: node.js, api, express, callback, nodemailer

I have created a `emailHelper` in my project for sending emails.

I wan to get a callback once the email sent successfully

```
//emailHelper.js

module.exports = {
    sendMail: (options) => {
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'SendGrid',
            auth: {
                user: keys.sendGridUsername,
                pass: keys.sendGridPassword
            }
        });
        const mailOptions = {
            from: options.from,
            to: options.to,
            subject: options.subject,
            html: options.content
        };
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return false;
            }
            else {
                console.log('mail sent');
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to save data to database only if the email is sent

```
const { sendMail } = require('../helpers/emailHelper');
mail: (req, res, next) => {
    const emailOptions = {
        from: 'from@email.com',
        to: 'to@email.com',
        subject: 'subject',
        content: 'text'
    };
    const mailResetLink = sendMail(emailOptions);
    if(mailResetLink) {
        //success save data
    } else {
        //failure trrow error
    }
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your sendMail in promise and return it:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject();
            }
            else {
                console.log('mail sent');
                resolve();
            }
        });
});
```

Than you would be able to do this:

```
sendMail(emailOptions).then(() => {
 // success save data
}).catch(() => {
 // failure trrow error
});
```

Using async/await you would need to change promise to return some identifier in any case, boolean in this case, and than tweak mail function:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
           transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    resolve(false);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('mail sent');
                    resolve(true);
                }
            });
    });

mail: async (req, res, next) => {
    const emailOptions = {
        from: 'from@email.com',
        to: 'to@email.com',
        subject: 'subject',
        content: 'text'
    };
    const mailResetLink = await sendMail(emailOptions);
    if(mailResetLink) {
        //success save data
    } else {
        //failure trrow error
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, tried your code getting this error `TypeError: undefined is not a promise
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at sendMail (D:\Workspace\Projects\doll4me\helpers\emailHelper.js:23:16)`

Comment: There was a typo in my answer, it is supposed to be 'new Promise' instead of 'Promise'. Edited the answer

Comment: and just for knowledge, is this the only way to achieve this. and what would code look like if we use async/await

Comment: This is the simplest way in this case. Theoretically you could use some events with for example RxJs, but it would accomplish the same with much more hassle in this case.

Comment: added async/await example

Comment: awesome :) thank you so much i really appreciate your time.